# .NET 5 App Service code gets removed on ARM template deploy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template, .net-5

I'm using ARM templates to create azure resources for my project. One of the applications is .NET 5.0 Rest API deployed as `App Service` with scheme as follows:

```json
{
    "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
    "name": "[variables('myWebsiteName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
      "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', variables('myWebsiteName'))]"
    ],
    "tags": {
      "environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
      "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('hostingPlanName'))]": "empty",
      "displayName": "MyWebsite"
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "[variables('myWebsiteName')]",
      "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
      "siteConfig": {
        "netFrameworkVersion": "v5.0",
        "appSettings": [
          {
            "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
            "value": "[reference(concat('microsoft.insights/components/', variables('myWebsiteName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
          },
          {
            "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
            "value": "[reference(concat('microsoft.insights/components/', variables('myWebsiteName')), '2015-05-01').ConnectionString]"
          },
          {
            "name": "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION",
            "value": "~2"
          },
          {
            "name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode",
            "value": "default"
          }
        ],
        "metadata": [
          {
            "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
            "value": "dotnet"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
 }
```

For deploy I use `ARM template deployment` task in `incremental` mode in `Azure DevOps`.

After I deploy ARM template I can successfuly deploy my application to `App Service` and its working correctly.
The problem is that if I re-deploy the same `ARM template`, then code from `App Service` gets wiped out. There is no code on the server, and entering website address shows only this sentence:

`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

How can I deploy my ARM template so the `App Service` stays intact if there weren't any changes in its template? It behaves correctly for another App Services, but this one always gets wiped out, even though `ARM template` doesn't change.

Comment: Hi @Peace, How are things going? Have you tried the suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please try it, and any progress, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Local machine deploys results in the same behavior. 
The suggestion about file not present is pretty obvious to me - code is being removed, so the web.config is not there. But the problem is that the code is wiped out, not a missconfigured web.config.

Comment: @peace did you find a solution for this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Below worked for me. My www was getting removed during arm deployment, even though the app service was declared in the template.

Adding this app setting solved the problem:

```
{ "name": "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE", "value": "1" }
```

hat tip goes to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53644221/25020